# Passing dependency to wrapper object via its constructor

Tags: c++

I have the following test:

```
TestGet(): _interface(), _db(_interface)
{
    _interface.get = mockGet;
}
```

which is used when testing this class:

```
class DB: public IDB
{
public:
   explicit DB(Interface_T& interface):
     _interface(interface)
   {
   }

   ...

private:
   Interface_T _interface;
};
```

Interface_T is a C interface implemented in a struct and passed to me from a C api. I wish to use the DB class as a wrapper around the C interface.

Notice however that DB copies the interface object to its member _interface. Therefore the line:

```
_interface.get = mockGet;
```

has no effect from the DB objects point of view although this was the intention when I wrote the test class. How would you rewrite TestGet() to remedy this error? How would you present to the client of the DB class that it copies the value passed to it?

Comment: Through UML diagram? This will be depicted as **Compositon**, that should make it pretty obvious to users of the class.

Comment: `DB` doesn't take ownership.  It creates a copy and owns its copy.  It's unclear what you mean by `_interface.get = mockGet` having no effect, at least without understanding what you intend it to do.

Comment: @jamesdlin The DB class will act as a C++ wrapper for the c interface.

Comment: This sounds like homework or exercises in a book. With some transcription erors. Why not **reveal the source** of the questions.

Comment: @ Cheers and hth. - Alf Its not! :/

Comment: And a sliced copy at that. Unless however a `typedef Interface *Interface_T` is in effect, which would be really vile (it's worse than evil -- "evil" means it has to be used carefuly, but this really shouldn't).

Comment: @Jan Hudec How is an object of type Interface_T being sliced here?

Comment: Taking ownership means you promise you are going to delete the object that was allocated and passed to you by pointer. You can't (well, technically can, but that would be really bad coding practice) take ownership of anything passed by reference and for things passed by value you don't take ownership, because you are making a copy.

Comment: @Jan Hudec I see, I will try to correct this in my post.

Comment: @Baz: Well, I presume `Interface_T` is conceptually an interface. That is a class meant to be derived and the subclass provides the actual implementation. But `DB::_interface` is of type `Interface_T`. It lives right there inside the `DB` object and only has room for the `Interface_T`, so if you pass instance of a subclass to `DB` constructor (you can; it takes a reference), only the `Interface_T`'s content and nothing of the subclass will be copied to the member. That's called slicing.

Comment: Jan Hudec: Interface_T is C interface (implemented in a struct) which is passed to me via a C API. Therefore, it shouldn't be derived, with the DB wrapper being used instead in the C++ code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Presuming that your intention is for `TestGet` to set a member on the `Interface_T` object used by `DB`, you can:

A. Defer construction of `DB`:

```
TestGet(): _interface(), _db(NULL)
{
    _interface.get = mockGet;

    // Using a raw pointer here for minimalism, but in practice
    // you should prefer a smart pointer type.
    _db = new DB(_interface);
}
```

B. If you have control over the `Interface_T` class, you could add a constructor that initializes `Interface_T::get` directly.  Then you could do:

```
TestGet(): _interface(mockGet), _db(_interface)
{
}
```

C. If you have control over the `DB` class, you could change it to share ownership of the supplied `Interface_T` (e.g. through `boost::shared_ptr`), add a constructor as in B, or add an accessor to its internal `Interface_T` member.

Comment: I would declare _db in the TestGet class with a shared_ptr. I don't want to share ownership of _interface. I want the DB constructor to say to the client that it should be used instead of _interface. This is because the DB class is a wrapper for the C Interface_T class.

Comment: The second can be used even without adding a constructor to `Interface_T`. Just create a function that returns appropriately prepared `Interface_T`, probably by value (reasonable compiler will optimize the copy away).

Comment: @Baz: I can't understand what you're trying to say.  Maybe actual code would help.

Comment: @JanHudec: A good point, but `DB`'s constructor inexplicably takes a non-const reference as an argument and therefore can't be used with anonymous objects.

Comment: @jamesdlin: In this case I'd just const-cast it away. Temporaries _are_ mutable, so it's well defined and it's probably a mistake anyway.

Comment: @JanHudec: You can't use `const_cast` to pass an anonymous object to a function taking a non-const reference.  And yes, temporaries are mutable, so it seems like a silly requirement by the language, but that's how it is.

Comment: @jamesdlin: I can certainly use the helper I added to my answer. You prompt me to actually test the const_cast; I'll come back with result. As for silly requirement, it is a safe-guard against accidentally having temporary copy modified when you wanted to have the original object modified. Yes, it get's in my way now and than too.

Comment: @jamesdlin: Yes, you are right, you need _two_ casts to get reference to temporary.

Answer (score 1):

So you need the interface to be correct by the time the db get's constructed. Well, it's easy. Just create appropriate interface in a function and pass the result to the constructor:

```
Interface_T makeMockInterface()
{
    Interface_T interface;
    // I presume you will first use the C API to initialize it and than
    interface.get = mockGet;
}

TestGet() : _db(makeMockInterface())
{
}
```

The `Interface_T` is returned by value from `makeMockInterface`, but since the underlying machine code actually returns objects by copying them to caller-provided space, most compilers will actually elide the copy and construct the object in the caller-provided space directly (this is explicitly allowed by standard).

The TestGet class does not need to have separate _interface member, because the _db contains it and they would not be shared anyway, so no point.

**Edit:** The `DB` constructor takes non-const reference, even though all it does is it copies the object and const reference is good enough for that. Fixing the constructor would be preferable, but if it's not an option, I'd cast it to non-const. That either needs *two* casts:

```
TestGet() : _db(const_cast<Interface_T &>(static_cast<const Interface_T &>(makeMockInterface())))
```

or a trivial template helper:

```
template <typename T>
T &lvalue_cast(const T &v) { return const_cast<T &>(v); }

TestGet() : _db(lvalue_cast(makeMockInterface()))
```

Since the temporary actually is mutable, just does not bind to non-const references as a safeguard, both are well defined.

Answer (score 0):

This is based on Jan Hudec comment above:

```
class TestGet : public ::testing::Test 
{
protected:
   TestGet() 
      :  _db(interfaceFactory())
   {
   }

   Interface_T interfaceFactory()
   {
      Interface_T interface;
      _interface.get = mockGet;
      return interface;
   }

   DB _db;
};
```

I like this clean approach.

Comment: If `DB`'s constructor takes a non-const reference as you had written, this isn't strictly legal.  You could, however, keep the `TestGet::Interface_T` member and replace `interfaceFactory` with a  `Interface_T& modifyInterface()` method that modifies and returns it.

Comment: @jamesdlin Then I should pass a const reference instead. The C interface contains a list of function pointers and these wont change once the interface is assigned to the DB object.

Comment: *Passing* a const reference doesn't matter.  `DB`'s constructor would need to be declared to *take* a const reference, assuming that you're able to modify the `DB` definition. (It doesn't make sense for `DB`'s constructor to take a non-const reference anyway since it copies it.  Alternatively it could take its `Interface_T` argument by value, and then it would be obvious to callers that it copies.)

Comment: @jamesdlin Yes I mean that DB's constructor takes a const reference.

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways, all including some kind of [inversion of control](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inversion_of_control).

My favourites are :

- pass the object to the constructor using the reference to the interface
- use the factory pattern to create the object, and return some kind of shared pointer (using interface again)

Something like this (assuming you have base abstract class):

```
struct Interface
{
  virtual ~Interface(){}
  virtual void foo() = 0;
};
struct Derived : public Interface
{
  void foo(){}
};

struct A
{
  A ( std::shared_ptr< Interface > obj_ ) : obj( obj_ )
  {}

  std::shared_ptr< Interface > obj;
};

//...
A myA( std::shared_ptr< Interface >( new Derived ) );
// ..
```

The above example is with passing to the constructor.